# SilverStripe 4.0 - status 403 when loading tinymce

Tags: .htaccess, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've just installed Silver Stripe 4.0 and everything seems ok beside...tinymce editor.

When I try to edit page there's a problem with loading tinymce.js. I get 403 error.

I don't know why but my htaccess in assets folder is set to 600. I tried to change it to 644 but after any action in CMS (for example refresh page) it returns to 600.

Comment: Do you have gzip related errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

same thing happened to me and took a while to figure out...

This is hosting dependent and will not happen to everyone depending on the server config (seems CPanel related..).

Basically SilverStripe always edits the permissions of private files at startup, that includes the `.htaccess` in the `assets` folder where images and the `tinymce.js` are. (This is why the permissions get reset all the time)

Adjusting your site config with the settings below should solve it (you can tweak the permissions if needed).

```
SilverStripe\Assets\Flysystem\AssetAdapter:
  file_permissions:
    file:
      public: 0644
      private: 0644
    dir:
      public: 0755
      private: 0700
```

Details and doc can be found here:
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/installation/common_problems/#i-ve-got-file-permission-problems-during-installation